# Using enum in data annotation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using a data annotation like so:

```
[RequiresAnyRole("Admin", "Member")]
```

I don't like passing strings as it can be a pain refactoring later but If I try to make an enum like so:

```
public enum Roles
{
    Admin,
    Member
}
```

And then try to cast the enum to string like so:

```
[RequiresAnyRole(Roles.Admin.ToString(), Roles.Member.ToString())]
```

Then I get the error:

> Error  CS0182  An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

My understanding of this error is that it has to be a string at compile time.  I have tried to make a static dictionary with the enum as the key but that didn't work either.

What is the best way to pass these values in a way that can be refactored later i.e. not passing in a string but passing in a reference of some sort that can be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). You can keep your enum, and do:

```
[RequiresAnyRole(nameof(Roles.Admin), nameof(Roles.Member))]
```

`nameof` expressions are constant expressions.

Of course, if you can change the attribute's declaration, you should change it to accept your `Roles` enum.